# How change mesh form with an armature bone

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, drivers, shape-keys

I want to change the shape by moving the bone along the x axis. how to do it?

meaning:

when bone x = 0.000. it's a basic shape

when bone x = 1.000. i want to change shape and save it to this state of bone(position x axis)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with some shapekeys and with a driver:

[image]

Create a cube, subdivide it, give it 2 shapekeys (one basis and a second one), keep the second one selected, go in *Edit* mode and round your cube with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (make sure that the factor is at 1 in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Create an armature at the middle of the cube or wherever you want (parent the cube to the armature if necessary). Right click on the shapekey *Value* of the cube and choose *Add Driver*:

[image]

Then right click again and choose *Edit Driver*, choose the bone as *Object*, set the correct *Type* and *Space* (here, *Local*). You can also right click and *Open Drivers Editor* in order to change the ratio:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that what i mean. Сan you advise ?Where can i read about it more?

Comment: I don't know, but if your struggle somewhere in the steps, please tell

Comment: So awesome! Works even better than I thought. But i have a question at part about Shape Keys. At 0.000 and 1.000 its perfect, but how edit intermediate result?(0.500)

Comment: maybe you can try to edit the curve (right click on the value and Open Drivers Editor and edit the curve (make it bezier with V > Aligned)

Comment: Got it, I'll try to figure it out! So easy and so powerful experience. Thanks for it